# Match letters in R regex

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I run the following

```
txt <- "client:A, field:foo, category:bar"
grep("field:[A-z]+", txt, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
```

Based on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) I expected I would get `field:foo`, but instead I get the entire string. Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to want to extract the value. Use `regmatches`:

```
txt <- "client:A, field:foo, category:bar"
regmatches(txt, regexpr("field:[[:alpha:]]+", txt))
# => [1] "field:foo"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/K1vfTC).

To match multiple occurrences, replace `regexpr` with `gregexpr`.

Or use *stringr* `str_extract_all`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(text, "field:[a-zA-Z]+")
```

Another point is that [`[A-z]` matches more than ASCII letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926). Use `[[:alpha:]]` in a TRE (`regexpr` / `gregexpr` with no `perl=TRUE`)/ICU (stringr) regex to match any letter.

Comment: This works very nice, but I still don't understand why the original attempt doesn't work?

Comment: @T'n'E In your code, you use [`grep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html). This function returns character vectors that match (or do not match if you invert the operation) the pattern. It does not *extract* the matches from the character vectors.

Comment: Ah, so I misunderstood the value to parameter to extract the value of the _match_, not the _matched string_. Confusing I think, but got it - thanks!